# Boolean modifier is not able to cut an hole on the head where are the eyebrows

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, edit-mode

I would like to merge the eyebrows with the head because I'm using a different object for them. I want to do this because when I try to deform the mesh of the head,the eyebrows aren't affected. So I thought to use the boolean modifier to cut an hole in the head in the same position where are located the eyebrows,but the boolean modifier didn't work as expected. Check the attached videos below. thanks.

[video 1](https://sendvid.com/qwjjnzdn)

[video 2](http://sendvid.com/u0t7a4v3)

Comment: That website has malicious content and page redirections.  Please consider converting the videos to gif and posting them as part of your question.  That way it's helpful for others in the future if the videos are removed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method, I'm not getting why you arent skinning the eyebrows to the bones you already have in your rig.

I wouldn't mess with booleans, that mesh looks like it has clean topology, wouldn't want to ruin that.

Comment: because I don't know how to skin the eyebrows to the bones.

Comment: the same way, you skinned body to the bones